# ImageView dinámico se resetea

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

Estoy usando un adaptador con BaseAdapter para poblar un listview personalizado, el cual tiene un ImageView donde quiero colocar imágenes dinámicas desde una web utilizando la librería universalimageloader.

Todo funciona muy bien, pero cuando "giro" el dispositivo, las imágenes se resetean y nuevamente inicia la "descarga" de las imágenes.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para evitar que las imágenes se reseteen y evitar descargarlas nuevamente cuando el dispositivo gira?

Pd. he colocado en el manifest

```
<activity android:name="example.myactivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
```

Aquí el código del adaptador:

```
 public class MyAdaptador extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;    String[] imagenes;    String[] titulos;    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdaptador(Context context, String[] cImagenes, String[] cTitulos) {
        this.context = context;        this.imagenes = cImagenes;        this.titulos = cTitulos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {        return titulos.length;    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {        return null;    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {        return 0;    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ImageView jImagen;        TextView jTitulos;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemcursos, parent, false);

        jImagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgImagen);
        jTitulos = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblTitulo);

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config=new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
        final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);
        String imageUri = imagenes[position];
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, jImagen);

        jTitulos.setText(titulos[position]);
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Mi actividad en su OnCreate

```
MyAdaptador Adapter;
    ListView miLista;

    String[] Imagenes; String[] Titulos;
    int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lytprinci);
        miLista = findViewById(R.id.lstPanel);

        int tNoti =1;
        Imagenes=new String[tNoti];
        Titulos=new String[tNoti];

        Imagenes[0] = "https://miweb.com/miimg.png";
        Titulos[0] = "El titulo";

        Adapter = new MyAdaptador(getApplicationContext(), Imagenes, Titulos);
        miLista.setAdapter(Adapter);

    }
```

Comment: Probaste con `screenLayout` en la propiedad `configChanges` del `manifest`? `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"`. Otra cosa, puedes probar si el metodo `onCreate` del `Activity `se esta llamando cada vez que giras la pantalla? para saber si el `Adapter` se esta recreando?

Comment: android:configChanges debe funcionar pero debes revisar cual es la Activity que contiene el Adapter tal vez el nombre no es el correcto "myactivity" @Jorny

Answer (score -2):

Independientemente del método que uses para cargar las imagenes, lo que sucede es que se vuelve a construir la actividad, por lo tanto los elementos que se encuentran en el `Adapter`.

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer para evitar que las imágenes se reseteen y evitar
>   descargarlas nuevamente cuando el dispositivo gira?

**Revisa que `Activity` contiene el `Adapter` y asegura que tenga la siguiente propiedad dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
```

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.